# [slam_toolbox]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'camera_depth_frame'...for reason 'Unknown'

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running slam_toolbox with an L515 Intel Realsense camera, and I always recieve this [INFO] message upon startup. After about a minute or so, the message stops, and then the system begins mapping as expected.

What is the cause of all these dropped frames?

```
[sync_slam_toolbox_node-5] [INFO] [1662493149.436859079] [slam_toolbox]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'camera_depth_frame' at time 1662493149.164 for reason 'Unknown'
...at time 1662493149.297 ...
...at time 1662493149.330 ...
...at time 1662493149.766 ...
...at time 1662493149.530 ...
...at time 1662493149.597 ...
```

Thank you for your help!

All of the needed frames and transforms appear to be published before and after the message stops: [TF Tree before and after](https://imgur.com/a/VGzUfbm)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/406027/%5Bslam_toolbox%5D:-message-filter-dropping-message:-frame-%27camera_depth_frame%27...for-reason-%27unknown%27/) by [LiquidTurtle1](https://answers.ros.org/users/107836/liquidturtle1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2022-09-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [khairulm](https://answers.ros.org/users/40864/khairulm/) on 2022-09-07**:
it could be that the TF2 transformations for the camera frame isn't up yet, try running `ros2 run tf2_tools view_frames.py` when the message appear, then run it again when the message disappear

**Comment by [LiquidTurtle1](https://answers.ros.org/users/107836/liquidturtle1/) on 2022-09-07**:
Thank you for your response, khairulm, I've updated my original post with more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That message comes from the message filters on TF - look into your TF tree and that the transforms are available and sufficiently high rate to transform the data on startup.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2022-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [LiquidTurtle1](https://answers.ros.org/users/107836/liquidturtle1/) on 2022-09-14**:
I was able to solve the issue by adding `{'depth_module.global_time_enabled': True}` to my launch file like so:

```
Node(
    package='realsense2_camera',
    namespace="camera",
    name="camera",
    executable='realsense2_camera_node',
    parameters=[set_configurable_parameters(configurable_parameters), {'depth_module.global_time_enabled': True}
                ],
    output='screen',
    arguments=['--ros-args', '--log-level', LaunchConfiguration('log_level')],
    emulate_tty=True,
    ),
```